# No hs_err_pid fiile are created on Windows 7 for installed Application

Tags: java, windows, crash, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a Java app that use a bunch of JNI calls to execute low level stuff on Windows. When I make the JVM crash voluntarily, I noticed that it is not producing any hs_err_pid.log file which would be very useful for debugging.

Here is the behavior:

- When I run it from Eclipse ==> The file is created in the current working dir
- When I compile my app and run the .exe ==> The file is created in the current working dir
- When I run the installer and run my app from the .exe in `C:\Program Files\...`, I still get the error message in the console that tells me the JVM crashed and a crash report has been created in `C:\Program Files\MyApp\hs_err_pid3060.log`, but the file does not exist.

Any idea on what's causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's caused by insufficient privilege of your app. The file writing by jvm has been blocked by the OS. You can try running your app with admin privilege and see if it works.